# NativeScript installation troubles

Tags: nativescript

I installed NativeScript with the script "Quick Setup" from the http://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win, I would like to know if all was installed succesfull. Because in command prompt run this: "tns doctor" and give error that tns is not recognized.

Does anyone know what to do to get this running?

I have Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to `npm install -g nativescript` to get the `tns` command. See http://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup#quick-setup.

Comment: Where I must exec that command? in command prompt "npm" is not recognized too.

Comment: In order to run "npm" command you need to have Node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: I recommnet that you follow this guide step by step because apart from Node.js you will need Java JDK and Android SDK as well + nativescript  - here is the link https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win